# How to convert decimal numbers to hours in spreadsheet or excel?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Wasnt able to find a working solution to convert decimal number into hours: 43,75 to HH:MM

[image]

in cell O11, one can see that the sum range is

```
=(sum(K5:K11))/60
```

The format of the cell and "J" row is "Number".

Formula in "J" row is (example):

```
=HOUR(J5)*60+MINUTE(J5)
```

Comment: I could not get it.  Your result 43,75 means 43 full hours and 0,75 hour.  0,75 hours equals to 45 minutes.  How do you want to show it ?  "43 hours + 45 mins" ?  Then you can add some text in your formula.

Comment: "43 hours + 45 mins" exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores date/time as days and fractions of a day.

So `minutes/60/24` gives the fractional day represented by `minutes`.

```
=SUM(K5:K11)/1440
```

and format the cell as `[hh]:mm`

or, as a text string:

```
=TEXT(SUM(K5:K11)/1440,"[hh]:mm")
```

Comment: none of the options work for some reason.
It gives me wrong numbers... But I do get your logic

Comment: @ReactNoob Please provide actual examples of the data, formula and formatting that give "wrong" numbers (as well as those wrong numbers).  It works perfectly well here, so there is something at your end I'm not taking into account.  For the `TEXT` function, you may need to use a semicolon instead of a comma; and it   Also, what region is your Windows set to.  (It may be that you don't use h=hour and m=minute in your regional settings).